# Apache dont run well my python code

Tags: python, apache, web, centos

First time here, i have a problem if you can solve me i will be very grateful to all of you.
I'm doing a HIDS project and i have this problem, when i run my code on linux (**CENTOS 6.3**) works great, but when i try to run it on a web script with **apache** just doesn't work very well. My code on **Python**

```
def sniffcometome(userbd,passbd):
    db= mysql.connect("localhost",userbd,passbd,"HIDS")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    proc = subprocess.Popen("ps -eo user | grep -v root | grep -v apache",shell=True,executable='/bin/bash',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (out,err) = proc.communicate()
    out = out.split()
    n = len(out)
    print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
    for i in range (n):
            sql = "select program from SNIFFER where program = '%s'"%(out[i])
            #print out[i]
            cursor.execute(sql)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            if result != None:
                    SendMail('ALERT: Sniffer detected!')
                    print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
                    print "Success"
    cursor.close()
    db.close()

    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
    print "Success"
```

when i run on Centos this the output

```
['USER', 'rpc', 'dbus', 'avahi', 'avahi', 'rpcuser', 'haldaemon', 'haldaemon', 'mysql', 'postfix', 'postfix', 'tcpdump']
```

when i run on APACHE only this the output

```
['USER']
```

Thanks guys! And have a nice day!

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the script manually exactly the same way? For instance: what user is running apache? You can check with `who am i`. Perhaps this user cannot see all processes?

Comment: i run this command this way "python hids_verif.py" in root and others users too and i get the list of the proccesses running. I check with "whoami" on my script and says "apache".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't you Apache server running inside a jail environment for security reason ? Are you sure that `ps` sees all inside this environment ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to see that, sorry i'm kinda new with linux and apache. Can you tell me please how can i see that? Thanks!